# Target all children by class between two other children

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#container .two").???.addClass("first");
$("#container .two").???.addClass("second");
```

Desired resulting code

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two first"></div>
  <div class="two first"></div>
  <div class="two first"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="two second"></div>
  <div class="two second"></div>
  <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target all similar classes between dissimilar classes. I can't use nth child because more "two" class elements may appear. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: @zerkms, wow didn't know this existed, nice!